# Band board in contact with ground- how to waterproof?

Tags: waterproofing, exterior, masonry, pressure-treated, ledger

[image][image]We recently bought a home built in 2004. During the inspection it was noted that there is what is assumed to be pressure treated wood "band board"or a ledger board (?)at the rear of the home adjacent to a patio. The house has a crawl space. There is masonry foundation in the front and sides of the house, but in the rear there is this two feet of treated wood buried with a few inches above ground. Should we excavate the area where the wood makes contact with the ground and waterproof? Should we replace with masonry? There is NO water currently going into the crawl space, but rain regularly flows towards this area.

Comment: It's odd that only part of the foundation is wood. I'm confused by your description, too. Please upload a photo somewhere and add it to your question.

Comment: Totally concur that it's "odd".. Showed pics today to a contractor who said he'd never seen the combo. Will try and upload photo

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear. In what dimension is the wood "2 feet"? There's no such thing as a 2' wide board, so what does it all look like? A wider photo would help.

Answer (score 1):

If it's properly treated for ground contact, "do nothing" works just fine. Entire foundations are made of properly pressure-treated wood.

Comment: Our concern is that we can't determine if it's "properly treated" pressure-treated wood.

Comment: Look for a grade stamp while you are digging around, or on the inside.